# Is it possible to use an array within a for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

This my code as it stands:

```
int sliderNum; // Variable Declaration //

// Loop Sequencer //
for (sliderNum = 41; sliderNum <= 48; sliderNum = sliderNum + 1)
```

However I need to change this so the loop no longer counts from `41`-`48` but instead counts e.g `73,71,34,46,52,4,17` etc. So a specific set of numbers one after another but not like counting normally.....hope that makes sense.

As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to this programming stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I think you should post more code and tell us what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 8):

```
int a[] = {1,4,7,10};

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
{
 ....process a[i] 
}
```

I recommend consulting a good book on [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Regarding the code: This is basically looping over an array with `iterations = size in bytes of the array / size in bytes of an element of array`

Comment: Should change "each" to "an" or to "any". Personally, I always use `sizeof(*a)`, so that I don't have to "choose an arbitrary index" (this is all semantic of course).

Comment: Yes, an array solves it. As the proverbial "level of indirection" usually does.

Answer (score 1):

You might even place the array literally within the `for` loop definion. This way, it somewhat resembles "with" statement, that is common in Python:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))

int main()
{
    for (int a[] = {73, 71, 34, 46, 52, 4, 17}, i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(a); i++) {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Personally, I wouldn't write such code on production, as it may be questioned as "too clever", whereas putting the array at the top of loop seems to make it more readable.

Comment: I find this code quite unreadable. Declaring the array before the loop would solve that. It should also be declared as `const`.